# Integral symbol in the denominator with standard size

Tags: fractions

How can I display the integral symbol in the denominator with the standard size. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. Please do not attach your code as an image, this makes it harder for us to use. If you add a Minimal Working Example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/90297) it would make it easier for us to answer your question. Also, what are you trying to achieve? Seems like you're getting the integral in the denominator just fine?

Comment: `\frac{1}{\displaystyle \exp....}` but are you _sure_ you want that??

Comment: THX David! It works!

Comment: I know it works but it will not be pleasant reading for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

You might use `\wfrac` as defined in another answer to a question of yours. But…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\wfrac}[3][3pt]{%
  \frac{\wfracterm{depth}{\dp}{#1}{#2}}{\wfracterm{height}{\ht}{#1}{#3}}%
}
\newcommand{\wfracterm}[4]{%
  \sbox0{$\displaystyle#4$}%
  \vrule width 0pt #1 \dimexpr #20+#3\relax
  \usebox{0}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\exp\Bigl(-\!\int p(t)\,dt\Bigr)\int q(t)\,dt \tag{Good}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\exp\bigl(\int p(t)\,dt\bigr)}\int q(t)\,dt \tag{Not so bad}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\int q(t)\,dt}{\exp\bigl(\int p(t)\,dt\bigr)} \tag{Bad}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\wfrac{\int q(t)\,dt}{\exp\int p(t)\,dt} \tag{Ugly}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Sure thing is that the code you show will produce a lot of errors, because blank lines aren't allowed inside `align` or any other math alignment environment.

The used tags are arbitrary strings of letters and by no means they denote judgment. `;-)`

Answer (score -1):

It looks very clean now with `\displaystyle`. Note that I also used `\cfrac`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

   \begin{align}
    
    = \cfrac{\displaystyle \int q(t) \,dt} {\displaystyle \exp{\int p(t) \,dt}}
    
   \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This code will generate errors because empty lines are not allowed in math mode. Note also that `\cfrac` isn't really doing anything useful here.